# Retrieve Query String Parameter Value Containing URL in MVC Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, url

I want to retrieve the query string value, but the query string parameter value contains the URL of another page, and not getting whole URL.

Check the Attached Screenshot.

In the image, I want to access the "id" paramter value that is "/defaulthealthchecktemplateitem/Item?id=1006&templateid=3&backTo=defaulthealthchecktemplateitem" but getting only "/defaulthealthchecktemplateitem/Item?id=1006".

```
  [TypeFilter(typeof(AuthorizationPrivilegeFilter))]
  [Authorize]
  [Route("home")]
  public class HomeController : Controller
  {
    public IActionResult Index(string id)
    {
      ViewBag.RedirectUrl = id ?? string.Empty;
      return View();
    }
  }
```

[image]

Comment: You have to show code that created that your picture url. Do you use an ajax?

Comment: yes, append URL to browser using "window.history.pushState("", "", ("/home?id="+url));"

Comment: You are sending a request to a server with the parameters that are after the question mark in the request (id=1006&templateid=3&backTo=defaulthealthchecktemplateitem).  The IActionResult is the response from the server.  The IActionResult type has to match the type and structure that the server returns in the response.  If the response is being return it should be in the object ViewBag.  You then need to add the property to the results 'View'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not an issue with the server-side code, it's an issue with the URL.  Because the URL contains query string arguments, there is currently in this example **no way** to discern between which arguments belong to the URL being requested and which belong to the URL that is itself a parameter value.

The way you account for this is by URL-encoding that value.  So this:

```
/defaulthealthchecktemplateitem/Item?id=1006&templateid=3&backTo=defaulthealthchecktemplateitem
```

Should be this:

```
%2Fdefaulthealthchecktemplateitem%2FItem%3Fid%3D1006%26templateid%3D3%26backTo%3Ddefaulthealthchecktemplateitem
```

The framework should automatically URL-decode the value when you retrieve it in the server-side code.